# Is the collection F of allfinite subsets of S and their complements always a sigma field?

Tags: probability

Is the collection F of allfinite subsets of S and their complements always a sigma field?
Well this a problem in my homework of Probability. I got confused the definition of Sigma field. How to solve it?

Comment: What do you think the definition of a sigma field is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand (from the definition of $\sigma$-field) why answering the question "is a countable union of finite subsets necessarily finite or has finite complement" negatively answer your question negatively.